# Rails not installing when following documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
$ sudo gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-3.1.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.1.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.1.1...
```

This did not properly work, as when I run `rails`, I get

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install rails
```

And doing `ruby --version` gives

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]
```

and doing `which rails` returns nothing. Anyone have any ideas about how I would go about installing the latest version of Rails? I've tries using the apt-get method, but I got Rails 2, however I need Rails 3 for my purposes.

Comment: How did you install your ruby? With apt-get?

Also, I believe you made a typo with `rails --version`, probably `ruby --version`, right?

Comment: Look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955559/the-program-rails-is-currently-not-installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the similar problem with my Ubuntu installation.
Solved it following to steps:

1. Make sure rubygems is installed
2. created the following symlink:

   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gem1.8 /usr/bin/gem