# How to clone and run another user's Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm attempting to do something I've never done before: clone another user's (codeforamerica) repository and run it locally on my computer with the intention of making my own changes to it.

I've managed to fork it to my own repositories, and cloned it:

```
git clone https://github.com/martynbiz/human_services_finder.git
```

...but when I do the following straight out the box:

```
cd human_services_finder
rails s
```

...it tell me:

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

...however, if I go into one of my own apps and run `rails s` it runs the server OK. Is there something missing I need to run this as a Rails app? Sorry, bit of a beginner with this one. Thanks

Comment: Could you find solutions to it here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760290/installed-rails-but-it-says-i-did-not

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955559/the-program-rails-is-currently-not-installed

Answer (score 23):

Below are the setups to run Ruby on Rails application on your system.

1. Make sure Ruby is installed on your system. Fire command prompt and run command:

   ```
   ruby -v
   ```
2. Make sure Rails is installed

   ```
   rails -v
   ```

If you see Ruby and Rails version then you are good to start, other wise [Setup Ruby On Rails on Ubuntu](https://railskey.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/setup-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu/)

Once done, Now

1. Clone respected git repository

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/martynbiz/human_services_finder.git
   ```
2. Install all dependencies

   ```
   bundle install
   ```
3. Create db and migrate schema

   ```
   rake db:create
   rake db:migrate
   ```
4. Now run your application

   ```
   rails s
   ```

Comment: what if there's a database included like mysql... how could we run it? it always say that rails cant connect to mysql or access denied.

Comment: I think `rake db:setup` is better in step 3.

Comment: does rake db:setup create the db's as well as setup?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install all the dependencies (Gems). This should be possible by running

```
bundle install
```

from the applciations directory.

If you are not using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) yet I would strongly recommend doing so.

Comment: Might also need ``rake db:setup``